# is this a flaw?

Tags: database-design, uml, visio, erd

In Visio I can only alter one side of the relationship.

If I want a "1-M" relationship,  I have to choose  "Identifying", but this automatically makes the FK becomes PK, which doesn't seem right to me.

[Someone with the same problem said it was a flaw](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/f52d3ab8-0f46-4626-b8ad-ce74043ade51/), so there is no way around it in visio?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "Required" is checked for the foreign key column(s) in the column list in the child table. If you do that you should see the relationship depicted as: -II--O<-, which I guess is what you want.

Comment: Even I checked the box "Required", the other side is still showing o+ （0 or 1）relationship